# Compiler error while returning Task.FromResult(MyInterface): cannot implicitly convert types

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, interface

I have two functions each returning an `ActualObject` instance, that implements interface `MyInterface`:

```cs
public class ActualObject : MyInterface
{
     ...
}

Task<MyInterface> GetObjectAsync()
{
    ActualObject obj = GetObjectInternal();
    return Task.FromResult(obj);
}

async Task<MyInterface> GetObjectAsync()
{
    ActualObject obj = await GetObjectInternalAsync();
    return obj;
}
```

`GetObjectInternal()` and `GetObjectInternalAsync()` both return the exact same object, just with two different implementations.

First method will give a compiler error: cannot implicitly convert from `ActualObject`to `MyInterface`, while second method compiles fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.FromResult(obj)` uses type inference to infer that you meant `Task.FromResult<ActualObject>(obj)`, and then fails to convert that task type to the interface-based task type. (`Task<T>` is invariant.)

To fix this, you just need to specify the generic type argument for the call to `FromResult`:

```cs
return Task.FromResult<MyInterface>(obj);
```

(Or you could declare `obj` as type `MyInterface`...)

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but how come I don't have the same problem for the second method? It is expecting to return `MyInterface`, but instead returns `ActualObject`

Comment: @gr0b0: For exactly the same reason as you can have method returning `object` but have a return statement with an expression of type `string` - the compiler validates the return type's compatibility, and does the right thing.